# error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token queue

Tags: c

```
struct nodePatient {
    struct Patient * patient; 
    struct nodePatient * next;
};

struct linkedQueue {
    struct nodePatient * firstNode;
    struct nodePatient * lastNode;
    unsigned size;
    unsigned maxSize;
};


struct PriorityQueue {
    struct linkedQueue * queue;
    int size;
    unsigned minPriorityValue;
};



struct PriorityQueue * createPriorityQueue(unsigned minPriorityValue) {
    struct PriorityQueue * newPriorityQueue = (struct PriorityQueue*) malloc (sizeof (struct PriorityQueue));
    newPriorityQueue->queue = (struct linkedQueue*) calloc (minPriorityValue+1, sizeof (struct linkedQueue));
    int i;

    newPriorityQueue->minPriorityValue = minPriorityValue;
    for(i = 0; i < minPriorityValue; i++) {
        newPriorityQueue->(queue+i)->maxSize = UNLIMITED_SIZE;
        newPriorityQueue->(queue+i)->size = 0;
        newPriorityQueue->(queue+i)->firstNode = NULL;
        newPriorityQueue->(queue+i)->lastNode = NULL;
    } 
    return newPriorityQueue;    
}
```

This is a part of my code and when i'm trying to compile i'm getting the fallowing errors:

[image]

What is it wrong in it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Just saying, `newPriorityQueue->(queue+i)->maxSize` is a pretty weird way to write a meaningful and understandable code.

Comment: You could do `(newPriorityQueue->queue+i)->maxSize = ...`. Not pretty, but should work. The traditional way would be `newPriorityQueue->queue[i].maxSize = ...`.

Comment: You are expoected to post text as text, not links or images.

Comment: "*i'm getting the fallowing errors: enter image description here*" so what keeps you from entering an image description though?

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
newPriorityQueue->(queue+i)
```

is wrong given your object types. Due to operator precedence `(queue+i)` is evaluated first. However, `queue` is not an independent variable. It is a member of the `struct`.

Hence, you need to use:

```
(newPriorityQueue->queue+i)
```

A syntactically correct line would be:

```
(newPriorityQueue->queue+i)->maxSize = UNLIMITED_SIZE;
```

You could make it more readable by using:

```
newPriorityQueue->queue[i].maxSize = UNLIMITED_SIZE;
```